# android call function from another class

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have main "tabHost" layout that its frame content is set on another layout "content" that contains a webview.
"Tabbar" class sets tabhost layout and "second" class sets its frame content.

Problem is when, from "Tabbar" class I try to set webview height using following code that crashes on params,

```
WebView webviewA = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewA);     
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) webviewA.getLayoutParams();
params.height -= 300;
```

Already tried to call function of webviewA from Tabbar as,

Tabbar class

```
second recalcula = new second();
recalcula.recalcula();
```

second class

```
public void recalcula (){
    webviewA = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewA);
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) webviewA.getLayoutParams();
    params.height -= 300;
    webviewA.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

also crashes on params... what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

logcat error

```
   07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023): java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at com.xxxxx.projecte1.second.recalcula(second.java:70)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at com.xxxxx.projecte1.TabBar.onReceiveAd(TabBar_iOSActivity.java:493)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at com.google.ads.internal.d.B(SourceFile:1116)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at com.google.ads.internal.c$e.run(SourceFile:187)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
    07-06 10:14:39.893: E/AndroidRuntime(11023):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add you log here, I think it could be error by calling function to set layout outside of UIThread. Maybe your logcat when program crashed would help clarify this.

Comment: posted, hope could help!

Comment: The problem created here would be the change of Context...You may not be having the context to access the variables and that would crash your app...i hope so..

Comment: and how to get then the context to acces to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection.

here an example;
http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-ile-reflection.html

Answer (score 0):

If the LayoutParams are called from another class rather than the activity then it is possible that in the import section is not the correct one. When is that case prefer to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams, or what the type of LayoutParams is, when setting or obtaining layout parameters.

In a view when you are trying to

```
setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT));
```

and the actual parent layout params are of a relative then it is a problem. Same case when obtaining them. I don't know why but in a non-activity class the layout params does not import the correct one at all times.